# Java DecimalFormat - incorrect number format in linux

Tags: java, linux, decimalformat

I have a problem with parsing decimal number in Linux environment. When I parse in Windows, everything's all right.

Below, code snippet

`String price;
DecimalFormat FORMATTER = (DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance();
double customPrice = FORMATTER.parse(price).doubleValue();`

And results

When price='9'     Then customPrice='9.0'    - it is ok

When price='1,00'  Then customPrice='100.0'  - it is wrong

When price='25,00' Then customPrice='2500.0' - it is wrong

Can you tell me what the problem is ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read here [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) about locales, probably you're using en_US which causes the ',' symbol to separate groups of thousands.

you can use also

```
DecimalFormatSymbols unusualSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
unusualSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
DecimalFormat weirdFormatter = new DecimalFormat(strange, unusualSymbols);
weirdFormatter.setGroupingSize(4);
```

to state your own sepeartors

Answer (score 1):

You can change the decimal separator of DecimalFormat. The easiest way by using a NumberFormat with the desired locale, e.g.:

```
NumberFormat FORMATTER = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
double customPrice = FORMATTER.parse(price).doubleValue();
```